# CSS Responsive Magento

Tags: css, magento, responsive

I'm working on making a responsive version of a magento theme on this website https://makedaadolls.com/store/

Why when I resize my window less than 750px, the html tag still has 980px of width?

Here is my css rule.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 750px) and (min-device-width: 320px){
    html {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 750px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least the responsive meta tag in your site header:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Then you need to make sure your header and main nav are also responsive (they currently are not). Basically this means all your containers need to have a max-width instead of a width. You won't need to set your html to be responsive using your media query in this case.